# Multiplicity of highest weights and representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am wondering whether there is a nice and clean way of detecting the dimension of an irreducible representation of a complex simple Lie algebra simply from the linear expansion of the corresponding weight in terms of the fundamental roots.

**Some background**: I want to study representations of parabolic subalgebras $\mathfrak{p}$ of complex simple Lie algebras, so we can assume $\mathfrak{g}$ is one of the classical $A_n,B_n,C_n,D_n$ or any of the exceptional ones. Dynkin diagrams give nice mnemonics for the *simple* roots of these simple Lie groups. Call $\mathfrak{h}\subset \mathfrak{g}$ a Cartan subalgebra.

Suppose I am only interested in 1-dimensional irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{p}$. Apparently there is a one-to-one correspondence between irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{p}$ and *dominant, integral* weights $\mu:\mathfrak{h}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

The theorem of the highest weight tells us that for each dominant integral weight there is exactly one (isomorphism class) of irreducible representation with that weight being the highest.

**Actual question**: is there a way that, from an expansion of a weight
$$ \mu = \sum_{\alpha\in \text{Simple roots}} c_\alpha \alpha$$
in terms of the roots of the algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ I can obtain the dimensionality of the corresponding highest wieght representation $V^\mu$?

This is my first serious attempt to study representation theory and its applications, so feel free to point towards any resources you might think useful and correct any conceptual mistake in the quetsion!

Comment: [Weyl's dimension formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Weyl_dimension_formula) is probably the easiest for computation but you can just get programs such as LiE to compute these for you as well

Comment: As for the remainder of the question, it is true that integral dominant weights correspond to irreps of $\mathfrak{g}$ but I was under the impression that representations of parabolic subalgebras were much more complicated. I believe that any parabolic subalgebra will stabilise a flag in any irrep of $\mathfrak{g}$ and the smallest subspace of that must be an irrep of $\mathfrak{p}$ but I don't know if these are then all distinct or if this covers all the possibilities for irreps of $\mathfrak{p}$

Comment: Thank you! The book I am following argues that irreps for the parabolic correspond to weights that are dominant and integral w.r.t. $\mathfrak{p}$ in some sense, meaning that the (co-)roots taken to construct the Levi subalgebra of the parabolic give integral non-negative coefficients when multiplied to the specific weight through the (dual) Killing form.

The Weyl formula is **precisely** the kind of result I was looking for!

Comment: Which book is that, may I ask?

Comment: [Baston & Eastwood, The Penrose transform](https://books.google.com/books?hl=es&lr=&id=_bs9DQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=penrose+transform+baston+eastwood&ots=nmqSCWF_W9&sig=Zl4cewScadBNKn6ydw7erTVbTtg)
In particular, Chapters 3 to 5, onto a proof of the Borel-Weil-Bott theorem.

Comment: Ah okay. I think the complications I was talking about arise because we are relaxing the conditions when we require it to be integral only w.r.t. $\mathfrak{p}$ and not w.r.t. $\mathfrak{g}$. They go on to restrict to the case that the weight is integral w.r.t. $\mathfrak{g}$ to ensure it gives a valid group representation as well and thus I believe all their $\mathfrak{p}$ representations are obtainable in the way I stated in my earlier comment

Comment: Could you check this following interpretation? Assuming that the weight $\lambda$ is already integral and dominant for $\mathfrak{g}$, I can compute the dimension of the $\mathfrak{g}$-irrep via the Weyl's formula, and furthermore the former irrep of $\mathfrak{g}$ coincides with the irrep of $\mathfrak{p}$ associated with $\lambda$ itself.

Comment: No the $\mathfrak{p}$-irrep is contained inside the $\mathfrak{g}$-irrep but it is not equal to it. Taking one of the examples in Baston & Eastwood, the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ descends to a action of $\mathfrak{p}$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ but this is not irreducible. Instead $\mathfrak{p}$ induces a filtration on $\mathfrak{g}$ and the lowest piece of that is the irrep. In the case that $\mathfrak{p} =\mathfrak{l} \oplus \mathfrak{u} $ where $\mathfrak{u}$ is abelian, this is exactly $\mathfrak{u}$.

Comment: To be more precise they consider $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p}$ as the rep instead but this is exactly the dual of $\mathfrak{u}$ (via the Killing form)